# Flow Record creation with multiple input values

Tags: visual-workflow, visual

We have an object whose all fields are filled up from a visual flow since this object consists of questions and answers. So, in Flow screen, we have a question which consists of picklist choice and a text field. So, user can select either any value in picklist or can enter any text.

I want a help on how this value can be assigned dynamically to the fields during record creation screen. That means, if in a session user selects picklist choice and after sometime during another flow run, if enters a value in text field and no picklist choice, then how to map these values in a single field since answer field is same for a question.

Comment: Did you try something

Comment: Yes, using the assignment. However, redirecting to one single record screen with the variable is bit difficult

Comment: Do you have sequence of question and answers section

Comment: Yes, depending on the answer choice or text field input the screen will be redirected to any random question which i have done through decision screen

Comment: Can you add each each question and answer on list after answer choice and you can perform a `Fast Update` at last.